# Facebook SDK changing height automatically

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have implemented Facebook Authentication in my app by using the Facebook SDK, but I face a weird behaviour of the login button. I have set the constraints of the `UIButton` and selected the custom class to `FBSKDLoginButton` which works fine. But when the app opens the button change the height of the button to something else.

[How it is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3jLo.png)

[How It was suppose to be:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csrxB.png)

Comment: Show your auto layout constraints.

Comment: problem in given constrain.. may be..

Comment: I can't post picture But I'm creating left, right and bottom constraints and height: 50px.

Comment: Why can't you post a picture?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement FB Login button is your create your **OWN UIButton**. Then just perform login in the `IBAction` of the button. That's easier and gives your flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this. I already solve the problem. I did it manually by creating a UIButton, creating his own Outlet and I added this func

Outlet:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var facebookLoginBtn: UIButton!
```

So

```
func configureFacebook(){

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 300, height: 50)
    facebookLoginBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 75, g: 100, b: 157)
    facebookLoginBtn.frame = rect
    facebookLoginBtn.center = self.view.center
    facebookLoginBtn.setTitle("Login with Facebook", for: .normal)

    // Handle clicks on the button
    facebookLoginBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector (self.loginButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    // Add the button to the view
    self.view.addSubview(facebookLoginBtn)
}
```

I also created a function to display the profile as soon as the user is already logged in on Facebook:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if(FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil){

        let toProfileVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileNavigationController")
        self.present(toProfileVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else{

    }
}
```

And now, to login with Facebook

```
func loginButtonClicked(){

    var login = FBSDKLoginManager()
    //Login facebook permissions and prints
    login.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: self) { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error?) in
        if (error != nil){
            print(error)
        }

        if let userToken = result.token{
            let token : FBSDKAccessToken = result.token

            self.nextPage()
            print("Token = \(FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)")
            print("User ID = \(FBSDKAccessToken.current().userID)")
        }
    }
}

func nextPage(){

    let toProfileVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileNavigationController")
    self.present(toProfileVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thank you guys!